IntelliJ converts special characters to different characters
I am trying to call a service in an application and filter the response I get from the service call.
response = serviceCaller.callMyService(request, endpoint);

if(isTrue){
    response.getSomeList().removeIf(obj -> !obj.getType().equals('Ö'));
}

There are objects in the list with the type Ö. So what I expect is that objects in the list with a type that is not Ö should be removed from the list. But in the response, special characters like Ö are converted to ' Ã–'. Because of this, the list is null but I expect to see objects with type Ö.
When I call the same service with Postman the result is not converted and I can see the type Ö but if it's called from the application as I'm trying to do it is converted to ' Ã–'. How can I fix this?

You're not using UTF-8, as you should be, but probably some Windows 7/8 bit encoding

You face a mojibake case (given below example in Python for its universal intelligibility): 'Ö'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252') returns 'Ã–' …
